# CakePHP 3 API does not authenticate user token

Tags: php, api, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, jwt

I'm developing a simple API project with CakePHP 3. This project uses JWT authentication. I followed this tutorial: http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/

The user's creation and token generation are running well, but when I try to access another controller, the application return is always 401 (unauthorized), even I'm sending the token. I don't know why the CakePHP can not authenticate.

I'm using Postman to test:[image]

As I told, the token generation works:

[image]

That's my `src/Controller/Api/AppController.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class AppController extends Controller
{

    use \Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait;

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Crud.Crud', [
            'actions' => [
                'Crud.Index',
                'Crud.View',
                'Crud.Add',
                'Crud.Edit',
                'Crud.Delete'
            ],
            'listeners' => [
                'Crud.Api',
                'Crud.ApiPagination',
                //'Crud.ApiQueryLog'
            ]
        ]);
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'storage' => 'Memory',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'scope' => ['Users.active' => 1]
                ],
                'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                    'parameter' => 'token',
                    'userModel' => 'Users',
                    'scope' => ['Users.active' => 1],
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'id'
                    ],
                    'queryDatasource' => true
                ]
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
            'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize'
        ]);
    }
}
```

That's my `src/Controller/Api/UsersController.php`:

```
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Network\Exception\UnauthorizedException;
use Cake\Utility\Security;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'token']);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $this->Crud->on('afterSave', function(Event $event) {
            if ($event->subject->created) {
                $this->set('data', [
                    'id' => $event->subject->entity->id,
                    'token' => JWT::encode(
                        [
                            'sub' => $event->subject->entity->id,
                            'exp' =>  time() + 604800
                        ],
                    Security::salt())
                ]);
                $this->Crud->action()->config('serialize.data', 'data');
            }
        });
        return $this->Crud->execute();
    }

    public function token()
    {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if (!$user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid username or password');
        }

        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'token' => JWT::encode([
                    'sub' => $user['id'],
                    'exp' =>  time() + 604800
                ],
                Security::salt())
            ],
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
        ]);
    }
}
```

That's my `src/Controller/Api/AreasController.php`:

```
use App\Controller\Api\AppController;

class AreasController extends AppController
{
    public $paginate = [
        'page' => 1,
        'limit' => 5,
        'maxLimit' => 15,
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'id', 'name'
        ]
    ];
}
```

That's my `config/routes.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different URLs to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;

/**
 * The default class to use for all routes
 *
 * The following route classes are supplied with CakePHP and are appropriate
 * to set as the default:
 *
 * - Route
 * - InflectedRoute
 * - DashedRoute
 *
 * If no call is made to `Router::defaultRouteClass()`, the class used is
 * `Route` (`Cake\Routing\Route\Route`)
 *
 * Note that `Route` does not do any inflections on URLs which will result in
 * inconsistently cased URLs when used with `:plugin`, `:controller` and
 * `:action` markers.
 *
 */
Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    /*$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
    $routes->resources('Areas');*/
    /**
     * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to a controller called 'Pages',
     * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
     * to use (in this case, src/Template/Pages/home.ctp)...
     */
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    /**
     * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
     */
    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    /**
     * Connect catchall routes for all controllers.
     *
     * Using the argument `DashedRoute`, the `fallbacks` method is a shortcut for
     *    `$routes->connect('/:controller', ['action' => 'index'], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);`
     *    `$routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', [], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);`
     *
     * Any route class can be used with this method, such as:
     * - DashedRoute
     * - InflectedRoute
     * - Route
     * - Or your own route class
     *
     * You can remove these routes once you've connected the
     * routes you want in your application.
     */
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
    $routes->resources('Areas');
    $routes->resources('Users');
    Router::connect('/api/users/register', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add', 'prefix' => 'api']);
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

/**
 * Load all plugin routes.  See the Plugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
Plugin::routes();
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I deleted the entire project folder and restarted the tutorial. Now it works. I don't what I was doing wrong.

Comment: This code shows generating new token. But, how could one validate the token and send back the response? In my case, any other API after login/register shows error saying "**You are not authorized to access that location**". How could it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your url `?/*name of token column*/=/*token*/`. For example:

`/coopermoto/api/areas?api_token=123` if it work you have problem with headers.